# How Can I set my Symfony 2 project to use parameters.yml instead of parameters.ini?

Tags: parameters, symfony

How Can I set my Symfony 2 project to use parameters.yml instead of parameters.ini?

in a controller, I can get variables from parameters.ini like this:

```
$this->container->getParameter('param_name');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your *app/config/config.yml* replace:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.ini }
```

with:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```